# find matrix such that $ Ax=(1,1,1)^t$ has exactly three distinct solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does there exist a matrix $3\times 3$ order such that $ Ax=(1,1,1)^t$ has exactly three distinct solutions? If so, find $A$.

I have no idea in this question please help.

Comment: Hint: the structure of the solution set is that of an affine subspace ($x_0+\ker A$), when not empty.

Answer (score 3):

**No:** 
$Ax=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is consistent implies the system possess only one or infinitely many solutions since, $x_0$ is a solution $\implies$ all solutions are obtained by adding $x_0$ to the general solution of the associated homogeneous system $Ax = 0.$

Comment: In other words, the solutions are in bijection with points in a vector space over our base field.  Can we have a vector space with $3$ elements?

Answer (score 2):

With a very liberal interpretation of the question, let $A$ be the matrix over $\mathbb{F}_3$, such that
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The solution of $Ax = [ 1,1,1 ]^T$ is $x=
[1,1,t]^T$, where $t\in\mathbb{F}_3$ is arbitrary. In other words, the equation has exactly three solutions.

Over other fields, the answer is no as already stated.